# Is it possible to set permission to other user for the table created by current user with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, created these 2 roles and grant different permissions to them.

```
create user user1 with login;
create role operator;
grant operator to user1;

create user user2 with login;
create role readwrite;
grant readwrite to user2;
```

When created a table by user1, such as `table1`, user2 can't use this table. It got permission denied.

Is it the right feature for PostgreSQL? If it is, how to make the table also can be used for user2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user1` has to grant `user2` permissions (via the role):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON newtable TO readwrite;
```

You can also define default privileges to have that happen automatically:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE user1
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON TABLES TO readwrite;
```

Now all tables created by `user1` will automatically have the right permissions.

Comment: Does the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE ... ON TABLES ...` also works for the new tables `user1` create in the future but not just for the current tables?

Comment: It only works for future tables, existing ones are not affected at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Then for the existing ones, is there a way to set? Or may I consider that, after we create a new schema, run the above grant command immediately(when 0 tables), for all the tables create later will work well between the two roles relation?

Comment: `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ...`

Comment: Great! I have set `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA main TO readwrite;`. Then `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA main FOR ROLE user1 GRANT ... ON TABLES to readwrite`. May I run `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, TRUNCATE FOR ROLE user1 ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA main TO readwrite;`(it includes `FOR ROLE user1`) for all?

Comment: No, you can only `GRANT` permissions in all tables in a schema, not to all tables owned by a certain user. If you want that, you'd have to grant them one by one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm clear now.